# How to get count of objects in NSArray inside of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need to get a count of the objects in array inside of NSDictionary. For example:

```
po _dictionary
{
    keys =     (
        "one",
        "two"
    );
}
```

Taking in consideration this is an array : `[_dictionary objectForKey:@"keys"]`

my question is how can I get the count in the array?

I try this :

```
[[[_tutorials objectForKey:@"keys"]  allKeys ]count];
```

but I'm getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray allKeys]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa419ea0'

Comment: This doesn't look like Objective-C...post your code so we can actually help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[_dictionary objectForKey:@"keys"]` is an `NSArray` and not an `NSDictionary`. Therefore, it doesn't understand the `allKeys` method. Drop it and it should work:

```
[[_dictionary objectForKey:@"keys"] count];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"%d", [[_dictionary objectForKey:@"keys"] count]);
```

As your `[_dictionary objectForKey:@"keys"]` is an array you can get the count directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", _dictionary[@"keys"].count);
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` has a method to get a `NSArray` of keys which I find is much more readable than using `objectForKey:`

```
[[_dictionary allKeys] count]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error1];

  NSLog(@"%d",[[res valueForKey:@"result"] count]);
```